# Can I use Android Beacon Library in foreground service, even on Android 8 (Oreo)?

Tags: android, service, ibeacon, beacon, android-ibeacon

### What I want to achieve

I am building an app for a shopping mall, with large amount of beacons installed not quite far away from each other (assume ~20m distance).
When a user walks in this mall, even without opening the app, the app needs to keep scan for beacons. When a beacon is detected, I will then query the server to ask if I need to and what local notification to push to user.

### What I planned to do

My original plan was to create a `Service`, returns `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()` in order to make sure that the service will restart itself even the app is killed by a task manager.

This `Service` will keep scanning for beacons.

In fact, this is the existing approach of my colleague. According to this colleague, the service starts almost immediately after the app was killed by a task manager.

### The problem

But soon I found that this approach is problematic.
The above approach has now 2 major problems:

- It drains batteries because it keeps scanning;
- It does not work on
  Android 8 due to [new limitations introduced in Android
  8](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html).

### My next plan

Although I know that `JobScheduler` can be used to replace Service, which is also the [existing approach of Android Beacon Library](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8), perform a scan every 15-25 minutes absolutely cannot fulfill my requirements, where beacons are very close to each other and therefore beacons need to be scanned frequently.

Therefore I come up with another plan:

1. Use Android Beacon Library to run background detection
2. Once the
   first beacon in filter list has been detected, start a foreground
   service (which will not be killed even in Android 8) that
   **continuously scan for beacons**
3. When all beacons in the filter has been exited, stop the above foreground service. Android Beacon
   Library shall resume to its background detection state.

The intentions of this approach are:

1. Make advantage of Android Beacon Library's background detection which saves battery, according to their [documentation](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html)
2. Step away of Android Beacon Library's handling of Android 8 due to its built-in limitation of long scanning interval
3. Scanning goes on even on Android 8 since I am going to use a foreground service

### My major question

By reading documentations, I already know how to scan for beacons in the background.
But how do I make use of Android Beacon Library to scan in a foreground service?
Plus, is there any problem that you can discover in the above approach / Do you have any better suggestions to achieve such requirements?

### My other question

In fact according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33521529/7870874), the background service starts **5 minutes** after an app is killed.
But by returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()` of a `Service`, it is restarted almost immediately.
Then, why will there be a 5 minutes delay, even in pre-Oreo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach is sound.  The Android Beacon Library 2.15+ natively supports foreground services as a scan mechanism for supporting cases like this on Android 8.  [See here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) for more info.

The tricky part is to switch back and forth between using Job Scheduler and a Service to do scanning.  I have not tested this, but my suggestion would be to bind manually to the BeaconManager in a custom Application class. 
Then :

1. On entering a region, stop monitoring and then unbind the BeaconManager.
2. Start a custom foreground service
3. In the foreground service, disable Scan Jobs, then bind to the BeaconManager and start ranging
4. Once no beacons have been ranged for a time, stop ranging, unbind from the BeaconManager, enable Scan Jobs, bind again and then start monitoring.
5. Finally, exit the foreground service

On the second question, yes, START_STICKY will very quickly restart a service on most platforms.  The library uses a 5 minute timer with the AlarmManager as a *backup*, which will relaunch the service if a START_STICKY restart fails.  Indeed, in typical use, the scanning service restarts much more quickly than five minutes.

Comment: Honestly I was expected you will come to answer, and I am so glad that you did lol. Thank you so much, but allow me to preserve the accept until testing complete!

Comment: In order to unbind the BeaconManager in step 1, I need to pass in a `BeaconConsumer`. Should my CustomApplication implements both `BootstrapNotifier` and `BeaconConsumer`? If yes, (1) Should I call `beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion()` inside `onBeaconServiceConnect()`? (2) Should I unbind my `beaconManager` in `BootstrapNotifier`'s `didEnterRegion()`, or `MonitorNotifier`'s `didEnterRegion()`?

Comment: OK, by looking at the source code of `RegionBootstrap`, I now understand that "stop monitoring and then unbind" is accomplished just by `bootstrap.disable()`. Then, how do I "disable scan jobs" in step 3 and "enable scan jobs" in step 4? It looks like `RegionBootstrap` does not have a `enable()` method; and binding a `BeaconManager` is occurred inside the constructor. Should I simply remove reference to the existing `RegionBootstrap` and construct another new one (And it will "enable scan jobs, bind again and start monitoring?)

Comment: Yes, you could create a new RegionBootstrap instance.  The lack of an enable() method is simply because it was designed mostly for one time setup use cases.   To disable scan jobs, you use `beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);  To enable them, you call with the parameter set to true.  By default, 8.0+ will use scan jobs unless you make the configuration change manually.  And to be clear, only make this configuration change if you are not currently bound.